# Cypher query with does not return anything if second part does not work

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query which supposes to join two results and give the union as output.

```
MATCH (:Some )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address) WITH collect(p) AS rows1
MATCH (:Some2)-[r*0..1]-> (pp:Address) 
WITH  rows1+collect(pp) AS rows2 
UNWIND rows2 AS row RETURN  row
```

As you can see the selection has two parts.  So it works fine if there is matching data for both queries but if the second part of the match does not return anything then it returns empty. Meaning `MATCH (:Some2)-[r*0..1]-> (pp:Address)`  returns empty then the whole union fails and returns null even if  `MATCH (:Some )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address)` return values .

How to fix this? Is it a bug in neo4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs  I used following version

```
MATCH (p:Address)
WHERE exist ((:Some )-[r*0..1]-> (p)) OR ((:Some2 )-[r*0..1]-> (p))
RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not actually asked a question (you have indeed just described the expected behaviour for **pattern matching** ... namely that if there is no match there is no result) ... but I assume you want a solution ?

```
MATCH (:Some )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address)
RETURN p
UNION
MATCH (:Some2 )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address)
RETURN p
```

should do the trick. Note that the only thing that matters is that the variables returned are exactly the same (what they contain doesn't actually matter).

Also ... you might want to have a look at what **OPTIONAL MATCH** does ...

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

**Update**

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
    MATCH (:Some )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address)
    RETURN p
    UNION
    MATCH (:Some2 )-[r*0..1]-> (p:Address)
    RETURN p",{}) YIELD value
RETURN value.p AS result
ORDER BY result;
```

Comment: i tried with an optional match ..  Is it a bug ? the normal union does not work for me because that does not work with count.  I want this to return aggregated count also

Comment: Then wrap the whole statement in an **apoc.cypher.run** and you can postprocess all you want ... I updated my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 1):

This simple query should work:

```
MATCH (s)-[*0..1]->(p:Address)
WHERE s:Some OR s:Some2
RETURN p;
```